# C program to C++ B+ Tree

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I usually code in C, but trying to learn C++ and I've been implementing an a B+ Tree and having some trouble with some errors. Here is my function

```
void print_leaves(node *root)
{
    int i;
    node *c = root;
    if (root == NULL) {
        cout << "Empty tree" << endl;
        return;
    }
    while (!c->is_leaf)
    {
        c = c->pointers[0];
    }
    while (true)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < c->num_keys; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", c->keys[i]);
        }

        if (c->pointers[order - 1] != NULL)
        {
            cout << " | ";
            c = c->pointers[order - 1];
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\Main\Desktop\test.cpp||In function 'void print_leaves(node*)':|
C:\Users\Main\Desktop\test.cpp|95|error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'node*' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\Main\Desktop\test.cpp|107|error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'node*' [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I've looked online and seen with malloc function this happens, but I'm not using it at the moment. Thaks

Comment: What is the type of node.pointers?

Comment: Apart from your use of `cout` this might as well be plain C...

Answer (score 3):

In C++, unlike in C, `void*` is not automatically converted to other pointer types.

You probably shouldn't be using `void*` in this program. A `node` should be pointing to other `node`s, not to unknown chunks of memory, so it is desirable to give these pointers appropriate type.